# ORDER BY multiple fields

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I have this query on the ORDER:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'b', 'p', 'j', 'i', 'a', 'c', 'v'), 
         FIELD(sex, 'M', 'F'), 
         user.name ASC";
```

But I need the result with the next order:

So I explained wrong, I guess I'm too tired of this. I need to get something like this.

```
order by (case 
when type = 'b' and sex = 'M' then 1
when type = 'b' and sex = 'F' then 2
when type = 'p' and sex = 'M' then 3
when type = 'p' and sex = 'H' then 4
when type = 'i' and sex = 'M' then 5
when type = 'a' and sex = 'M' then 6
when type = 'c' and sex = 'M' then 7
when type = 'v' and sex = 'M' then 8
when type = 'j' and sex = 'M' then 9
when type = 'i' and sex = 'H' then 10
when type = 'a' and sex = 'H' then 11
when type = 'c' and sex = 'H' then 12
when type = 'v' and sex = 'H' then 13
when type = 'j' and sex = 'H' then 14               
end) asc, name asc;
```

But this code is not working. This is the result I get:

```
 | a | F |
 | a | F |
 | a | M |
 | v | M |
 | j | M |
```

Any idea to make the query clear?

Comment: I would use `CASE`

Comment: i see no problem with the existing query.

Comment: Your code should do what you want.

Comment: Yes, it does. I explained wrong. Sorry. Going to post again at the end with the full code I need.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using order by case as mentioned by Radim :

```
order by (case when type = 'b' and sex = 'M' then 1
              when type = 'b' and sex = 'F' then 2
              when type = 'p' and sex = 'M' then 3
          end) asc,name asc;
```

This is only for example You can add your remaining conditions further in when clause.

Comment: Having all conditions in a single `CASE` increases the number of possibilities to `type * sex` (14) instead of `type + sex` (9).  It's better to check for each condition separately, and `ORDER BY` the appropriate columns, in this case `type, sex, name`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from t
  order by case when type = 'b' then 1
                when type = 'p' then 2
                when type = 'j' then 3
                when type = 'i' then 4
                when type = 'a' then 5
                when type = 'c' then 6
                when type = 'v' then 7
           end,
           case when sex = 'M' then 1
                when sex = 'F' then 2
           end,
           name;
```